# Limit !dumpheap (windbg) output to n objects

Tags: windbg

When using windbg and running !dumpheap command to see the addresses of objects, how can you limit to a specific number of objects. The only way I found was using CTRL+BREAK
and a command line on a blog http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/07/04/dumpheap-parameters-and-some-general-information-on-sos-help-system/

-l X - Prints out only X items from each heap instead of all the objects.

Apparently -l no longer exists in SOS.dll

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you manage to figure out an answer?

Answer (score 9):

What are you actually looking for? Before looking at individual objects, it's usual to narrow the area of interest.

The –stat switch shows a summary, per type of the objects on the heap.

**DumpHeap** [-stat] [-min ][-max ] [-thinlock] [-mt ] [-type ][start [end]]

- The -stat option restricts the output to the statistical type summary.
- The -min option ignores objects that are less than the size parameter, specified in bytes.
- The -max option ignores objects that are larger than the size parameter, specified in bytes.
- The -thinlock option reports ThinLocks. For more information, see the SyncBlk command.
- The -mt option lists only those objects that correspond to specified the MethodTable structure.
- The -type option lists only those objects whose type name is a substring match of the specified string.

The start parameter begins listing from the specified address. The end parameter stops listing at the specified address.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx).

Comment: I am looking for individual objects. -stat -min 100 -max 150 shows me 150K+ small objects.

Comment: SUppose you have 150k entries all of the same size and type (as in my case) - how on earth can you find out a single adress of one of it? If you print out the complete list your're doomed there is now way to interrupt the listing for the next 30 minutes (except killing the process)

Comment: with `cntrl + break` you can be lucky with killing the output before it gets unwieldy

Comment: My modern laptop has no such "break" key. Oh, the progress! (The UI for version 1.2103.01004.0 also locks up so the button nor ctrl+c work but may for others)

Answer (score 9):

According which criteria would you like to limit the number of outputs?
The -l option just limits the output according to line numbers. This is useless: let's say it shows only the first 10 objects, maybe the object you're looking for is not even listed.

If the output is too long for WinDbgs output window, use .logopen to dump the objects into a file and then review the file with a text editor.

If you have other ideas how your object looks like, you can perform a loop over all objects

```
.foreach ( obj { !dumpheap -short -type MyType} )
```

and then decide with `.if` whether or not your object matches this criteria.

As an example, I was looking for a needle in a haystack. I was searching a specific Hashtable in a program with more than 3000 Hashtables on the heap. The command I tried to use was

```
.foreach ( obj { !dumpheap -short -type Hashtable }) {.if (poi(poi(${obj}+1c)) > 100) {!do ${obj}} }
```

`1C` is the offset of the count member of the hashtable.

`100` is the number of items the Hashtable was expected to have at least.

Unfortunately it didn't work for Hashtables immediately, because `!dumpheap -type` also listed HashtableEnumerators which somehow crashed the debugger.

To dump hashtables only, run `!dumpheap -stat` and figure out the method table of hashtables and run the command with `-mt <methodtable>` instead of `-type <classname>`, which gives

```
.foreach ( obj { !dumpheap -short -mt <MT of Hashtable> }) {.if (poi(poi(${obj}+1c)) > 100) {!do ${obj}} }
```

Comment: For future readers: you should be able to use `-mt` with the method table address of `HashTable`. You get that information by running `!dumpheap -stat` and then look for `HashTable` for the method table address.

Comment: @xxbbcc: You're right. Meanwhile I use that as well. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Your answer was very helpful in tracking down a memory leak.